# How to search for value in array using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a column which stores values in array form like below

> table_name : records
>
> column_name : data sample
>
> row 1 : ['John','Adam', 'Mike']

I am trying to apply query something like below

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE data IN('Adam');
```

which is giving 0 results found.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

The IN clause with one parameter is essentially the same as `WHERE data = 'Adam'`, wich search for the exact value. 
Since your row contains a different string from Adam, no results are returned.
The query for your situation should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE data LIKE '%Adam%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using JSONArray , you can try query using `JSON_CONTAINS()` function.
you can query like below:-

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, '[Adam]');
```

where **data** is column which contains the array.